# How can I repeatedly change the background style of a div using a click event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the background property of each day on a calendar, when clicked, between blue and green using javascript and CSS. like a toggle function. The default color is blue, and I've managed to get each day to turn green when clicked but I can't figure out how to change them back to blue.

Here's what I've tried.

```js
const days = document.getElementsByClassName('day')

for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.style.background != 'linear-gradient(#7ce8b6, #00ff2a)') {
      e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#7ce8b6, #00ff2a)'
    } else if (e.target.background != 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)') {
      e.target.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)'
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.day {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid rgb(29, 29, 116);
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF);
}
```

```html
<div class="day">1</div>
<div class="day">2</div>
<div class="day">3</div>
<div class="day">4</div>
<div class="day">5</div>
<div class="day">6</div>
<div class="day">7</div>
<div class="day">8</div>
<div class="day">9</div>
<div class="day">10</div>
```

Comment: Hey Robin, wouldn't it be better to toggle a class on the div? Something like that `e.target.classList.toggle('day-green')`

Comment: The "day-green" class should contain styles for turning the background blue, so when the class is up - the browser changes the background, and when it's not - the browser gets everything back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a CSS class that has the style for green background color and using javascript, just toggle that class on each `div` element.

```js
const days = document.getElementsByClassName('day');

for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    days[i].classList.toggle("green");
  });
}
```

```css
.day {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid rgb(29, 29, 116);
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF);
}

.green {
  background: linear-gradient(#7ce8b6, #00ff2a);
}
```

```html
<div class="day">1</div>
<div class="day">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
} else if (e.target.background != 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)') {
  e.target.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)'
}
```

probably needs to be changed to:

```
} else if (e.target.style.background != 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)') {
  e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)'
}
```

so that it is the same as the first if statement.
ive not been able to simulate the code yet, however just reading through it logically i picked up on this possible typo.

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.day {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid rgb(29, 29, 116);
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF);
}
</style>

<div class="day">1</div>
<div class="day">2</div>
<div class="day">3</div>
<div class="day">4</div>
<div class="day">5</div>
<div class="day">6</div>
<div class="day">7</div>
<div class="day">8</div>
<div class="day">9</div>
<div class="day">10</div>

<script>
const days = document.getElementsByClassName('day')

for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.target.style.background);
    if (e.target.style.background != 'linear-gradient(rgb(124, 232, 182), rgb(0, 255, 42))') {
      e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CE8B6, #00FF2A)';
    } else {
      e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)';
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when testing my browser was detecting the color as RGB, therefore by changing the hex values into the RGB range, it will now change back

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you're right about the typo but unfortunately correcting it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: sorry, just tried your edit. This works fine. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you click on div, browser give it's color as RGB like :
style="background: linear-gradient(rgb(124, 232, 182), rgb(0, 255, 42));"

so should edit your code as like this:

```
 const days = document.getElementsByClassName('day')

 for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.style.background != 'linear-gradient(rgb(124, 232, 182), rgb(0, 255, 
   42))') {
    e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CE8B6, #00FF2A)';
   } else {
  e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)';
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things are wrong with your CSS.

1. You are checking the value of `background` style property but since you are using a liner-gradient, so it will be attached to `background-image` available via `backgroundImage` in js
2. You are checking for css property sat via class, therefore you need to use `getComputedStyle()` to get the currently active property of background image
3. You are skipping the style in your `else if` thus not being able to set the property i.e you are using `e.target.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)` instead of   `e.background = 'linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF)`
4. Browsers can render the colors in different formats then Hex e.g RGBA in firefox

Following is a fixed snippet cleared of the above issues which is working as expected:

```js
const days = document.getElementsByClassName('day')
console.clear();
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  days[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const style = getComputedStyle(e.target).backgroundImage;
    console.log(style);
    if (style != 'linear-gradient(rgb(124, 232, 182), rgb(0, 255, 42))') {
      console.log('green');
      e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(rgb(124, 232, 182), rgb(0, 255, 42))'
    } else if (style != 'linear-gradient(rgb(124, 185, 232), rgb(0, 255, 255))') {
      console.log('blue');
      e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(rgb(124, 185, 232), rgb(0, 255, 255))'
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.day {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid rgb(29, 29, 116);
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(124, 185, 232), rgb(0, 255, 255));
}
```

```html
<div class="day">1</div>
<div class="day">2</div>
<div class="day">3</div>
<div class="day">4</div>
<div class="day">5</div>
<div class="day">6</div>
<div class="day">7</div>
<div class="day">8</div>
<div class="day">9</div>
<div class="day">10</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation and css.

```js
document.querySelector('.days').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if (ev.target.matches('.day')) {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('other')
  }
})
```

```css
.day {
  height: 4rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 5px solid rgb(29, 29, 116);
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(#7CB9E8, #00FFFF);
}

.day.other {
  background: linear-gradient(#7ce8b6, #00ff2a);
}
```

```html
<div class="days">
  <div class="day">1</div>
  <div class="day">2</div>
  <div class="day">3</div>
  <div class="day">4</div>
  <div class="day">5</div>
  <div class="day">6</div>
  <div class="day">7</div>
</div>
```